# How to insert text in one of the tabs of the jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: 2013, custom-form, form, jquery-ui

I am attempting to implement a tabbed SP form, with fields and text, using JQuery UI Tabs. I have tried several methods, but each has its limitations:
When I edit the "New Item" form and place the fields code inside the Tabs divs, I can place text in one of the tabs, and all the fields work just fine, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the Date field (line 200) gets placed outside of the tab area. I have tried placing it above other fields, with the same result.
[image]
[image]

I have also tried the Hillbilly forms, and they work fine for all the form fields, including "Date", but I don't know how to inject text in one of the tabs or in-between fields.
Any help would be really appreciated.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Y0awZS13VLw5in7JDamJ3TKaYGJ34Kq

Comment: Thank you for responding - I have tried it with multiple forms, and different lists. The same problem occurs with the Date field. Could it be specific to my environment?

Comment: Thanks, I have dropped the code file in my drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Y0awZS13VLw5in7JDamJ3TKaYGJ34Kq

Comment: a) I have a Content Editor web part that references the file with these references: jquery-1.12.4.js - a local copy; https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js; https://spcs3.kc.army.mil/asaalt/USAASC/SiteAssets/jquery/lightness/jquery-ui.css; https://spcs3.kc.army.mil/asaalt/USAASC/SiteAssets/jquery/Demos/style.css;

Comment: Under the references, I use a simple call: <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>

Comment: b) No, I left the existing form alone, and created a new form.Yes, I used the jqueryui.com/tabs

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have tried it out. I was not able to make it to work with my limited time and knowledge in new custom form.
But I was able to render it fine using this [link](https://www.markrackley.net/2015/12/03/tabify-your-sharepoint-forms/) and in a new default form. There is a video in this link, you may want to follow that.
Please follow that link, any new columns that you add also get added. Let me know if this helps or still you need to go with only having the tabs implemented in custom form?
If you want to go with the form, please post full custom form code and share it only with me and remove any domain names please. Don't reveal your domain names like you have posted in the above comments. 
Below is the screenshot from what I have tried.
[image]

Comment: I have also been able to get it to work with that method - the only problem is that I don't know how to add text to another tab, or under certain fields. This method takes the form fields and places them into tabs, which is great. But what if you just want to add text to one or more tabs, in addition to fields?

Comment: OMG! I think I have a workaround! All you need to do to insert text, is add it to the "Description", under additional column settings. I think this will work for me. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: glad you figured it out. Yep there is that description thingy for each form Field....:)